# Appending to array inside of class is not actually appending to the calling object?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm instantiating an object in the ViewController.swift and then I call a method of the object so that I can append values to one of its members. However, when I try to access the newly appended values I am receiving an "Index out of range error". More specifically I'm trying to append `newProduct : Product` to the class member `products : [Product]` inside of the methods `getAllProducts()` and `populateProducts`. After I append though, the initial calling object `client : ThreeDCartAPIClient` in the ViewController does not actually retain any of the info from the internal class methods. Why is this?

I've tried using "self" pretty much everywhere inside the class methods and calling the methods from an initializer but I keep getting the same result.

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var featuredButton1Image: UIImageView!

    let head : HTTPHeaders = [
        "SecureUrl"  : "https://someURL.3dcartstores.com/",
        "PrivateKey" : "99999999999999999999999999999999",
        "Token"      : "11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "ContentType": "application/json"
    ]
    let ENDPOINT_URL = "https://apirest.3dcart.com/3dCartWebAPI/v1/"

    var client = ThreeDCartAPIClient()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Hide the navigation bar on main screen
        viewWillAppear(true)

        // Make API request and load content
        loadInitialUI()
    }


    func loadInitialUI() {

        client.getAllProducts(url: ENDPOINT_URL, header: head)

       // ******* Here I get an "index out of range" *********** //
       featuredButton1Image.image = client.products[0].mainImage

    }
}
```

```
// ThreeDCartAPIClient.swift
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ThreeDCartAPIClient {

    var products : [Product]

    init() {
        products = [Product]()
    }

    func getAllProducts(url: String, header: [String : String]) {
        Alamofire.request(url + "Products", method: .get, headers: header).responseJSON {
            response in // Start of a closure inside of Alamofire method
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                // Force unwrap the result value
                let jsonResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)

                // Populate each product field now
                self.populateProducts(json: jsonResponse)
            } else {
                print("Failure")
            }
        }
    }

    func populateProducts(json : JSON) {
        for (_, product) in json {
            let newProduct = Product()
            newProduct.sku.setSKU(json: product["SKUInfo"])
            newProduct.shortDescription = product["ShortDescription"].stringValue
            newProduct.mainImageFile = product["MainImageFile"].stringValue
            Alamofire.request("https://SomeURL.3dcartstores.com/"
                + newProduct.mainImageFile).responseData { (response) in
                if response.error == nil {

                        if let data = response.data {
                            newProduct.mainImage = UIImage(data: data)!
                        }
                }
            }

            products.append(newProduct)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling asynchronous APIs. They run their completion handler at some indefinite time after you all them (or perhaps not ever). You can't just access the value right after kicking the process off, you have to wait for it to finish.

Comment: Thank you I had a feeling this may have been it. Is there a way that you may know of to wait for the API call to finish before accessing the object?

Comment: You can use a `DispatchGroup` inside the `populateProducts` method, I think that will help you.

Comment: @BrandonMain There are multiple approaches, but unfortunately, none of them have the status of "end-all-be-all". You can use the delegate pattern, a completion handler, NSNotificationCenter, or a concurrency library like PromiseKit or (my favourite), RxSwift. (you can google all those things). The easiest to start with would be a completion handler, but Rx is the most expandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completing  async task you will get data in products array. Because of async task you can’t get data instantly. 
you can use delegation for notified when the task is completed. 
Write a protocol in your ThreeDCartAPIClient.swift file:

```
protocol JsonResponseProtocol: class {
    func asyncTaskCompleted()
}
```

Inside ThreeDCartAPIClient class write:

```
weak var jsonResponseDelegate: JsonResponseProtocol?
```

When completed all data population (in your case write it outside the for loop in populateProducts() ):

```
self.jsonResponseDelegate?.asyncTaskCompleted()
```

in your viewController after declaring var client = ThreeDCartAPIClient() add this (inside viewDidLoad()):

```
client.jsonResponseDelegate = self
```

Then in your viewController.swift write this:

```
extension ViewController: JsonResponseProtocol{
 func asyncTaskCompleted(){

    // if data populated successfully you can access from here 
}
}
```

For better practice you can send data Array in asyncTaskCompleted() from your ThreeDCartAPIClient class.

Comment: This line `client.jsonResponseDelegate = self` gives me an "Expected declaration" error

Comment: can you write/ give screenshot of updated ThreeDCartAPIClient class ?

Comment: where did you write : client.jsonResponseDelegate = self ? you can write it after : super.viewDidLoad()

Comment: Adding it after super.viewDidLoad() works, but I'm still getting the "index out of range error" :(

Comment: Ok i moved `featuredButton1Image.image = client.products[0].mainImage` into the `asyncTaskCompleted()` method and it's working, thank you very much!

Comment: thats what I have written in the comment inside asyncTaskCompleted() method. welcome